# Definition of the limit as infinity(function)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I know the definition of $\lim_{x\to \infty}f (x)=L\in \Bbb R $ as:

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists M : \forall x> M \Rightarrow \vert f(x) -L \vert \ < \epsilon $$

But why don't we defined it as:

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists M : \forall x \geq M \Rightarrow \vert f(x) -L \vert \ < \epsilon ?$$

Is it okay when we defined it as the second version(including the "=")? Intuitively, It still make sense though we adding the "=" since the $x$ goes to infinity.

Comment: These definitions are equivalent. Try to understand why.

Comment: We cold also use (equivalently) ${} \le \epsilon$ in either of these.

Comment: You can also put a constant before $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is right. You can just take some $M' > M$ from your first definition, and you will immediately have $x \geq M' \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.